# Issue with Chrome - jquery/javascript not working after Ajax

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, xhtml, hide, show

I am facing a strange issue with Chrome. I am trying to fix this issue in a page which is not developed by following any w3c standards. I can say almost 1000+ w3c issues.

The error is on a "onclick" function which is working fine before the ajax call. After ajax call, we are getting the content filtered (including the links with onclick). The functions is for .show() a container and .hide() another container., and which is working fine when the initial load. But after the links get refreshed using ajax, the .show() and hide() is not working (visually no change in the browser). But I found that the function call is happening well even after the ajax. I tested this by providing an alert in the function. But the .show() and hide() inside the function is not happening.

I found one strange behavior that, when I inspect element by right click on the links, the show() and hide() in the functions are working fine.

There is no issue with Safari, IE, Firefox, etc, the issue is only with Chrome.

Hope some extperts here can help me to solve this issue.

Here the code:

### HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="swap(1)" >Show hotels in area</a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="swap(2)">Show hotels on map</a>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr id="hotelArea" style="display: none">
<td>
<!-- Hote Area Content here -->
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="hotelsMap" style="display: none">
<td>
<!-- MAP Content here -->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### Javascript after the html (this is at the bottom of the page):

```
function swap(n){
if(n==1){
$('#hotelsMap').hide('slow');
$('#hotelArea').show('slow');
}
if(n==2){
$('#hotelArea').hide('slow');
displayHotelsOnMap();
$('#hotelsMap').show('slow');
}
}
```

I also tried to use .live(click) instead of the inline onclick, but same issue happened....
Thanks in advance
-sunil

Comment: thanks for the question. updated my question with code..

Comment: there are too many possibilities without seeing the code that does the filtering, sounds like that's where the issue is.

Comment: Don't think there is an issue with filtering code as this is working when I do a Inspect element in Chrome by rightclick on the link which open/hide the continer...!

Comment: Don't think there is an issue with filtering code as this is working when I do a Inspect element in Chrome by rightclick on the link which open/hide the continer...! and this issue is only in chrome(tested and working fine in Safari, IE, FF etc...!

Answer (score 0):

Use [better JavaScript links](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/javascript-only-links) to eliminate side effects. Replace the anchor with a span element to avoid the [void() function conflict](http://mbaierl.com/2009/09/a-void0-javascriptvoid0.html) and move the onclick to a [jQuery .click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of debugging, please try to re-run the js script after the ajax call. I would put your javascript in a .js file and re-run it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       //your ajax call
       $.getScript("yourjs.js");
 });
```